# Accumulation points in $R^2$ and general $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So I am solving at the moment question of this form first if we take this question. Determine the accumulation point in $R^2$ and if they are closed sets ,open sets, or neither.

All complex numbers z such that $|z| > 1$

$S =  \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| >  1 \} = \{z = x + iy: x^2 + y^2 > 1 \}$

So according to intuition I can easily see that S` which is the set of accumulation points is the following:

$S` = \{ Z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \geq 1\}$, however I can't seem to prove it rigorously in terms of the euclidean metric as computations are weird maybe I am not familiar with it yet. I can solve such question in the easy euclidean metric in $R^1$ but $R^n$ metric makes the computations much harder. If someone could show me the technique that would be great.

In the following question above we need to prove that $S`$ is the only accumulation points that is if we consider any ball $B(z`,r)$ such that $z` \in S`$ then $(B(z`,r) - {z`})\cap S` \neq \emptyset$ for any r > 0 and any set outside $S`$ we can always find a counter example.

Edit:

So I was able to prove it first of, however I am having troubles proving to myself outside of $S'$ it will be not accumulation points.

Suppose $S' = \{ z' \in \mathbb{C}: |z'| > 1 \} = \{z' = x' + iy' : x'^2 + y'^2 > 1 \}$

Now consider arbitrarily $r > 0$ and consider $z \in B(z',r)$, where z' is arbitrarily element in $S`$.

\begin{align} 
d(z',z) < r &\implies (x - x')^2 + (y - y')^2 < r^2 \\
&\implies x^2 + y^2 + x'^2 + y'^2 - 2xx' - 2yy' < r^2 \\
 &\implies x'^2 + y'^2 < r^2 - [x^2 + y^2] + 2xx' + 2yy' 
\end{align}

So we have 
\begin{align} 
1 < x'^2 + y'^2 < r^2 - [x^2 + y^2] + 2xx' + 2yy' \implies
1 < x^2 + y^2 < r^2 - [x`^2 + y`^2] + 2xx` + 2yy`
\end{align}

However, we know that $x'^2 + y'^2 > 1$ along with inequality above we have $x^2 + y^2 > 1$, so we must have that for any z $\in B(z',r)$ and any r > 0 we have $(B(z',r) - {z'})\cap S \neq \emptyset$.

However I am trying to show myself that for $S'^c$, then we won't have any points, @ColdNumber I see it intuitively however I can't prove it rigourously.

Comment: In your edit, why does $(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2< r$ imply that $x^2+y^2+x'^2+y'^2-2xx'-2yy'<1$?

Comment: sorry I meant to say that is less than $r^2$ along with the fact that $x`^2 + y`^2 > 1 $ we get $x^2 + y^2 > 1$

Comment: I have edited it again please check !

Comment: I don't see how you got to $x^2+y^2>1$ from the other inequality.

Comment: @coldnumber I have edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll address the accumulation points question.

Points whose modulus is strictly greater than  1 will be interior points, so they are automatically accumulation points. To prove this, you could say that if $|z|>1$, then $|z|=1+\varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon >0$, so $B(z, \frac \varepsilon 2)\subseteq S$, so $z$ is an interior point of $S$.

Similarly, points $z$  whose modulus is strictly less than 1, will have $|z|=1-\varepsilon$, so the open ball $B(z, \frac \varepsilon 2) \subseteq \Bbb C\setminus S$, meaning the ball contains no points of $S$ and hence $z$ cannot be an accumulation point of $S$.

For points on the boundary $|z|=1$:

You can represent these as $e^{i\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle the ray from the origin through the point makes with the real axis. (I'm thinking of the complex plane.)

Then you can show that a point $z=e^{i\theta}$ in the boundary will be the limit point of the sequence $\{(1+ 1/n)e^{i\theta}\}$, all of whose terms are in $S$ because their modulus is $1+1/n>1$ , and this will show it is an accumulation point of $S$ (because it shows that any open ball around $z$ will contain infinitely many points of the sequence and hence infinitely many points of $S$.)

---

**EDIT:** I will expand on why a point $z$ with $\left| z\right|<1$ cannot be an accumulation point of $S$.

To show that $z$ is not an accumulation point, we just need to find an open ball around $z$ that contains no points of $S$.

If a point $z$ has modulus less than $1$, meaning $\left| z\right|<1$, for some positive number $\varepsilon$ we have $\left| z\right| =1-\varepsilon$.

Consider the open ball  $B(z, \varepsilon)$.

If $z' \in B(z,\varepsilon)$, then $\varepsilon >\left| z'-z\right|$. By a variation of the triangle inequality, $\left|z'-z\right|\geq \left|z'\right|-\left|z\right|$, so we have the following:
\begin{align}
 \varepsilon  &> \left|z'-z\right|\geq \left|z'\right|-\left| z\right|=\left| z'\right|-(1-\varepsilon)\\
\varepsilon  &> \left| z'\right|-(1-\varepsilon)\\
(1-\varepsilon)+\varepsilon &> \left| z'\right| \\
1&>\left| z'\right|
\end{align}

We have shown that any point in the open ball $B(z,\varepsilon)$ is not in $S$, which means that $B(z, \varepsilon)\cap S = \varnothing$, so $z$ is not an accumulation point of $S$.

Comment: @Dude: What you  want me to explain is why points with $|z|<1$ cannot be accumulation points, right?

Comment: @Dude: edited. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just 1 question how did you get $|z| = (1 - $\epsilon)$ is it the same epsilon as the ball or different one !

Comment: It's the same epsilon. If a point has modulus less than 1, you can write it as 1 minus some positive number epsilon (now epsilon is fixed, so it's no longer arbitrary). Then you can form the ball around it with radius epsilon, and it is fully contained in the ball of radius 1 around the origin because epsilon is less than 1 (because the modulus has to be nonnegative. I recommend you try to draw this, because that is how I got to the answer.

Comment: Alright yes the drawing agrees with the math, however when I try to do it using the fact that r : = min(|z|, 1 - |z|). I don't get the proof however. when I try that r, but according to the picture we should indeed get the proof.

Comment: It's not really necessary, because even when $|z|<1-|z|$, the ball around $1-|z|$ is fully contained in the ball centered at the origin of radius 1 (this actually is what I proved in my answer). But if you want to use that $r$, you can split the proof into cases: case 1 is  $r=|z|$ and case 2 is  $r=1-|z|$. Then case 2 is in my answer, and here is case 1:  Since min($|z|,1-|z|)=|z|$, we have $1-|z|>|z|$, meaning $2|z|>1$ and $1>2-2|z|$. Also, $r=|z|>|z'-z|\geq |z'|-|z| \iff 2|z|>|z'|$. But we also have $2(1-|z|)>2|z|$, so putting all inequalities together $1>2-2|z|>2|z|>|z'| \iff 1>|z'|$.

Comment: 1 moment I gotta go I will be back I will read this bit of information after I come back as your answers is quite informative !

Answer (score 3):

Let's prove the statement for $\Bbb R^n$ (the process is completely analogous for $\Bbb R^2$):

Let $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ be an arbitrary point of $S'$ and let $\delta$ be an arbitrary positive real number.

For each $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\},$ let $r_k$ be a rational number that satisfies $x_k<r_k<x_k+\frac{\delta}{\sqrt n}$ if $x_k\geq0$ or $x_k>r_k>x_k-\frac{\delta}{\sqrt n}$ if $x_k<0.$

It is easy to see that if $r=(r_1,\ldots,r_n),$ then $\|r\|>1$ and $\|r-x\|<\delta,$ so that $(B(x,\delta)-\{x\})\cap S$ is not empty, which proves that $S'$ is a subset of the set of all accumulation points of $S.$

To prove that $S'$ is **the** set of all accumulation points of $S,$ let $y\in\Bbb R^n-S'.$ Then $\|y\|<1.$

Let $\varepsilon:=\min\{\|y\|,1-\|y\|\}$ (We do not consider the case when $\|y\|=0$ for obvious reasons). Then $B(y,\varepsilon)\subseteq\Bbb R^n-S'.$

Therefore $S'$ is the set of all accumulation points of $S.$

Comment: what about points outside of S`?

Comment: In the last part I proved (or at least gave you a sketch of the proof) that given any point $y$ in the complement of $S'$ (which is $\Bbb R^n-S'$), we can always find some open ball around $y$ that do not intersect $S'$ at all (and thus it do not intersect $S$) so that $y$ **cannot** be an accumuñation point of $S.$

Comment: Alright good I get it but I wanted to ask how come you deduced that it is the $\epsilon := min\{||y||, 1 - ||y||\}$?

Comment: Draw a picture of the complement of $S'$ in $R^2$ (because it is easier to see it in the plane) and consider some arbitrary point inside the circle $S$ (can you see that $\Bbb R^2-S'$ represents a circle in $R^2$?).

Comment: Okay good perfect thanks alot for your informative answer !

Comment: And yeah I could see R^2 - S` represent a circle in $R^2$